# Is it possible to use a single input to input several numbers that the program will simultaneously use?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a road network and in order to minimise the number of input boxes needed I want to use a single input box , in the user interface, to be able to code for the multiple connections between nodes (by using numbers as the input that corresponds to a node).Is this possible , if so please could you show me some code examples? cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! The simplest way to do this is to just have the user enter a list literal (e.g. `[1 2 3]`) in the input box:
[image]

You can the read the value of this global as a list like so:

```
read-from-string my-list
```

In this case, that would return `[1 2 3]`.

Another way would be to have the user enter one number on each line:

[image]

Then you can get that as a list with `read-from-string (word "[" my-list "]")`. Actually, in this case, the numbers can be separated by any kind of whitespace, not just newlines, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: does the same process apply if I wanted to use colours instead of numbers?

Comment: Yup! Although it's a little weird, colors *are* numbers in NetLogo. See [the NetLogo color documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors).